# Way to avoid either casting or additional allocations?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, memory, allocation

Let's say I have a class that has an int and an array of 10 objects.

Assuming I had to allocate a million of these, it is expensive because first I have to allocate the container object, then the int, and finally the array.

To avoid an allocation, I can instead have an array of 11 objects, with the first index being the int. This way, I don't have to allocate the container object. After profiling, I've found this speeds of the code by quite a bit.

I was wondering if I was missing something or if there was some greater solution. Either I have the container object and the code is much prettier and more generic, but it executes slower due to the additional allocation, or I instead resign myself to having to cast the 0th index to an int each time I want to access it, and lose elegance of code.

**Edit: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that these arrays are sometimes moved around and thus I need reference type semantics to avoid copying over the entire array and instead just the reference. For that reason I don't think I can use structs unless there's a solution to that as well.**

Comment: Personally, I would not try to optimize this type of thing.  Additionally, unless the array is containing an object that uses the same amount of memory as the int, your wasting space with the additional allocation inside of the array.

Comment: Also, the improved readability is a huge plus in most circumstances due to maintenance down the road.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a real performance issue? If not, stick with the nice code.

Comment: This program has been working for weeks. All I've been doing is optimization since then. This is very important to me.

Comment: You need to profile your application to see whether this allocation is actually a performance problem or you're wasting your time.

Comment: I've been profiling. It is.

Comment: What objects do you store at the array? It seems the type casting can be reduced using interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using structs like this:

```
    public struct Test
    {
        public int m_nObj;
        public object[] array;
    }
    ....
     Test[]  pTest = new Test[1000000];
     for(int i = 0 ; i <  1000000; i++)
     {
         pTest[i].array = new object[10];
     }
```

Average time for class = 32ms;
Average time for struct = 21ms;

Total Code:

```
class Program
{
     public struct Test
    {
        public int m_nObj;
        public object[] array;
    }
    public class Test2
    {
        public int m_nObj;
        public object[] array = new object[10];
    }
    public class Test3
    {
        public object[] array = new object[11];
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            Stopwatch dtStart = new Stopwatch ();
            dtStart.Start();
            Test[] pTest = new Test[1000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                pTest[i].array = new object[10];
            }

            dtStart.Stop();
            GC.Collect();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Struct = " + dtStart.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            dtStart = new Stopwatch();
            dtStart.Start();
            Test2[] pTest2 = new Test2[1000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                pTest2[i] = new Test2();
            }
            dtStart.Stop();
            GC.Collect();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Class int = " + dtStart.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            dtStart = new Stopwatch();
            dtStart.Start();
            Test3[] pTest3 = new Test3[1000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                pTest3[i] = new Test3();
            }
            dtStart.Stop();

            GC.Collect();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Class no int = " + dtStart.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("=============================");
        } 
    }
}

Results:
Struct = 252.2253
int = 396.9113
no int = 262.9782

Struct = 266.8878
int = 399.845
no int = 473.181

Struct = 313.7979
int = 446.8496
no int = 411.5755

Struct = 364.6454
int = 389.0763
no int = 553.3433

Struct = 298.1766
int = 424.2794
no int = 441.8867
```

Comment: I don't see how making it a struct helps. It's going to go on the heap regardless because there's a million of them.

Comment: It is, but there is no ctor call.

Comment: Isn't this still slower than just having the object array? I'll benchmark real quick.

Comment: Nope, faster since you are skipping a function call to the implicit constructor

Comment: Side note: 20-30ms measured with `DateTime` means almost nothing. Please make sure to use `Stopwatch` for such measurements.

Comment: The differences for larger arrays is ~100ms

Comment: Have you tried using the ref keyword in your functions to pass the struct by ref instead of value.

Comment: Also, as a side note. Have you throught of maybe creating a pool of these objects and then reusing them if allocation is that big of an issue (create 10x objects and then use one pool at a time)

Comment: Are these results from the release build with optimizations?

Comment: Release optimization for x86 build

Comment: I posted a complete console application to the answer, run it and the time difference is pretty clear.

Comment: I am using object pools. I'm testing results in release mode with optimizations on without the debugger. I don't *think* ref will work in all instances but I'll investigate.

Comment: Updated the code to use StopWatch and structs are ALWAYS faster. Good luck with your optimizations, also try to NOT intialize your object array until you actually need to use it and minimize the number of elements if you can.